# Broker and Linking log not generating- SDL Tridion 2009 SP-1

Tags: content-delivery

I want to generate the Broker and Linking log in debug mode. I made the following changes in cd_broker_conf.XML and CD_LINK_CONFIG.XML

```
<Logger Level="debug">
  <FileLogger Level="debug" Location="D:/Tridion/log/cd_broker.log" 
                            MaximumFileSize="5M" NumberOfFiles="5"/>
</Logger>
<Logger Level="debug">
  <FileLogger Level="debug" Location="d:/tridion/log/cd_link.log" 
                            MaximumFileSize="5M" NumberOfFiles="5"/>
</Logger>
```

But still I cannot see the respective logs, for linking 
Could you please suggest what steps do I need to take. Note in our deployer server following services are running.

1. Tridion Monitoring Service
2. Tridion Content deployer
3. Tridion Cache Channel service

Looking forward for reply..

Comment: Did you restart your app server?

Comment: Do all services have proper permissions to the directories?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at some posts on the good old Tridion Forums, I suspect that it is the format of your XML that needs tweaking.

First of all, I think that the file paths to the log files are case sensitive.  You may want to double-check these.

Also, it appears that your slashes should go the other way.  Taken from the Forums [here](https://forum.tridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7387&SearchTerms=FileLogger) (login required):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="5.4">
    <Global>
        <Logging>
            <Logger Level="error">
                <FileLogger Level="error" Location="C:\tridion\log\cd_broker.log"/>
                <!-- <ConsoleLogger Level="debug" Trace="false"/> -->
            </Logger>
        </Logging>
        ...
    </Global>
...
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Paths are never case sensitive on Windows (the XML elements and attributes are), and I believe the slashes could go either way on the old config files.

Comment: I seem to remember the paths in the cd_broker_conf.xml being case sensitive and suspected that the log configuration may be the same.  This is also what Ryan says at the bottom of his accepted answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10556210/197993

Comment: I never seem to have come across that on a Windows machine, unix is a different story of course. But maybe I'm wrong, can never harm to keep case sensitivity in paths.

Comment: Yeah, it was a defect on an old GA - 5.3 or 2009, can't remember which

Answer (score 4):

If the configuration file contains errors like incorrect naming of attributes or non closed tags etc., then the respective service cannot determine where to log to. In that case the logging is diverted to the default logfile called `TRIDION.LOG` which is written in the Windows Temp directory.

Usually it can be found in `C:\Windows\Temp`.

Look for that file and see what errors are mentioned in there and solve them. Then after fixing the config files, yu can remove the errors from the `TRIDION.LOG` file or delete it and restart the Content Delivery services. Your `TRIDION.LOG` file should now remain empty (or in case you deleted it, it should not be generated at all).